# Create ADF pipeline that uses a web activity to retrieve data from binary blob and passes that content to an API call&#39;s body

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

The requirements: Create a pipeline that picks up a file (txt, xlsx, pdf, ppt) from an Azure Storage Blob and makes an API call with the file's content in the body to push it to an application.

- I have created a data pipeline that uses a web activity (Get Blob API call) to get the content of that blob. The blob is configured as binary since I don't know what filetype the file will be (either txt, xlsx, pdf, ppt) - **Name of the activity: 'Get Content of the files from Blob'**
- I have created a second web activity (push the file into an application) that makes an API call. The documentation of this endpoint suggests that the file has to be added in the body in binary format. Therefore, I have set the body of this call to be `@activity('Get Content of the files from Blob').output.response` - **Name of the activity: 'Push file into application'**

However, I noticed that the response part of the output of the web activity 'Get Content of the files from Blob' looks like this:
[image: output of web activity]

The specific file I am using to test the pipeline is a .xlsx file. The binary representation looks like it's missing characters. When the second web activity is invoked with that string as body, it ends up pushing in the application a specified xlsx file that is corrupted.

What is the correct way to pick up inside a data pipeline the correct binary content of the binary blob and use it in a subsequent API call to push it somewhere else? Ultimately, can this happen solely in an ADF pipeline?

**Note**: If I instead use a txt file, the process runs smoothly and the txt file can be seen in the application normally.

This is the configuration of the first activity ("Get Content of the files from Blob")
[image: Get Content of the files from Blob]

And this is the configuration of the second activity ("Push file into application")
[image: Push file into application]